# How can I implement the same widget that Django uses to ManyToMany fields in the admin page?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, django-widget

My models:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    BASE_UNIT_CHOICES = [("g", "Grams"), ("ml", "Mililiters")]
    CURRENCY_CHOICES = [("USD", "US Dollars"), ("EUR", "Euro")]

    ingredient_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    base_unit = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=BASE_UNIT_CHOICES)
    cost_per_base_unit = models.FloatField()
    currency = models.CharField(
        max_length=3, choices=CURRENCY_CHOICES, default="EUR")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
    quantity = models.FloatField()
    ingredient_id = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} / {self.ingredient_id}"


class Recipe(models.Model):
    recipe_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(RecipeIngredient)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('Date Created')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}, {self.ingredients}"
```

When I use the admin page, it has this + button that allows me to create new ingredient/quantity combinations

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqP2i.png)

But when I try to  use it from a form in my code it looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8GhL.png)

Here is my form code:

```
class AddRecipeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ['name', 'ingredients', 'date_created']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write the 'widgets' for each field in you Form that need configuration.

Check the documentation '[Widgets in forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields)', or even, you can define your own [Widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/).